# how to define separate controller for an included view in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two separate views (named view1.html and view.html) with separate controllers (named controller1 and controller2) and they are routed using config:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'view1.html', controller: controller1}).
    when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'view2.html', controller: controller2}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

view1 and view2 have a shared part of template code, so I extracted it into a new template view (named view3.html) and use ng-include in view1.html and view2.html:

```
<span ng-view="">
    ...
    <span ng-include="'view3.html'"></span>
    ....
</span>
```

also view3.html logic is independent from the controller1 and controller2, so the scope variables needed in veiw3.html is repeated in both of the controllers:

```
function controller1($scope){
    ...
    some code to calculate $scope variables for view3
    ...
}
function controller2($scope){
    ...
    same code to calculate $scope variables for view3
    ...
}
```

My question: is there any way to extract repeated codes in controllers into a separate controller for view3? I add ng-controller for view3 but it doesn't work:

```
<span ng-controller="controller3">
   view3.html template codes here
</span>
```

I guess it's because view3.html is included in an element with ng-view directive and can not have a separate controller.

Comment: My understanding is that the canonical approach would be to refactor the common controller code to a service, and invoke it from your controllers.  I am somewhat new to angular but the things I've read suggest this is the "proper" way.

Comment: This should work. What is the problem there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `ng-include` to achieve it:

In view1.html

```
<div ng-include src="'view3.html'"></div>
//other template for view1
```

In view2.html

```
<div ng-include src="'view3.html'"></div>
//other template for view2
```

In view3.html

```
<div ng-controller='controller3'>
    //template for view3
</div>
```

Comment: I did this (as I explained in the question) but it doesn't work. scope variables of controller3 is not visible in inside <div ng-controller='controller3'> </div>

Comment: @Ali ng-include creates a child scope. scope variables of controller3 is definitely visible in the controller3. If you need to access the parent scope in view3, you need $parent variable to do that.